# How to link all word appearances of one specific word to one place

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it possible to link all specific word appearances in a document to one specific place inside the document (definition of it) automatically?
Linking word appearances to bookmarked definition is one option, though it requires manual linking for each appearance.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use find and replace.  Create your first hyperlink to the bookmarked definition.  Select it and copy to clipboard (ctrl c).  Then in find and replace, search for the word in find and in replace type ^c (when you replace, the text you search for will be replaced by the clipboard text, which is your hyperlinked text).